# Spring app - persisting key/value to properties file without escaping

Tags: java, spring, properties-file

I have a Spring application (stand-alone, not a WebApp) and I'm trying to write a method that will persist a new key/value pair to application.properties .
This is what I have done:

```
public static void AddUpdateAppSettings(String key, String value) {

    File f = new File("application.properties");

    try {
        Properties props = new Properties();
        props.load(new FileInputStream(f));
        props.setProperty(key, value);

        OutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(f);
        DefaultPropertiesPersister p = new DefaultPropertiesPersister();
        p.store(props, out, "Updated by application");
    } catch (Exception e) {
        Console.WriteLine("Error writing app settings");
    }
}
```

The two problems I can't seem to get around are:

1. All empty lines are removed (trivial)
2. The values are 'escaped' during the read/write process, e.g. the value `process.ClusterPrefix=####` becomes `process.ClusterPrefix=\#\#\#\#` after processing

I've also tried without the `DefaultPropertiesPersister`, i.e. just calling `props.store(out,"");` with the same outcome

Do I need to preprocess the InputStream, or is there some way to turn off escaping?  What about empty lines?

**edit**
As noted, escaping does no harm when it symmetrical, but 
This file should be human-editable, and it's difficult when the read/write process converts `process.backupPath=C:\Temp\Backup` into `process.backupPath=C\:TempBackup`

Comment: `Console.WriteLine` is it java? :)

Comment: Yes - you caught me though - I wrote some simple static functions to make the code more comfortable to another Developer who's coming from C# :)

Answer (score 0):

Based on the [docs](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E23095_01/Platform.93/ATGProgGuide/html/s0204propertiesfileformat01.html):

> Lines that start with the comment characters **`!`** or **`#`** are ignored. **Blank lines are also ignored.** 
>   A property value can span several lines if each line is terminated by a backslash (‘\’) character.
>   The backslash character must be escaped as a double backslash.
>   The characters **`newline`**, carriage return, and tab can be inserted with characters **`\n`**, \r, and \t, respectively.

So **`#`** is the system character for Java properties and if you want to store the key or the value with the **`#`** in it, you need to escape this character.

And don't worry about it, after reading this property, the value will contain no escape characters.

Save property:

```
 props.setProperty("test#key", "test#value");
```

**application.properties** content after saving:

```
test\#key=test\#value
```

And the value after read:

```
String value = props.getProperty("test#key");
System.out.println(value); // test#value
```

Comment: OK there are other issues with the escaping though.  This file should be human-editable, and it's difficult when the read/write process converts `process.backupPath=C:\Backup` into `process.backupPath=C:Backup`

Comment: @Black the \ symbol must be escaped too :) If necessary to edit properties files manually, you can manually escape these symbols. Or you can use something like `jboss tools properties editor`, or your own app that will do the same (escape bad characters)

Comment: so, in summary, there's no reasonable programmatic way in Java to avoid either problem?

Comment: @Black yes, you can't store the value with escape-characters without escaping them.

Comment: Well, I can stop using `Properties` and create my own text properties reader/writer.. I just didn't want to do that if `Properties` allowed overriding their formatting rules

Comment: @Black I think that escaping characters is quite logical :) All formats (e.g. json, xml, properties) are have characters that must be escaped. If you will use your own format, maybe later you will have such a need :) And if my answer satisfies you, please mark it as correct. GL :)

Comment: I'll just keep it open a while longer - maybe someone knows something that will already allow me to either disable or self-define escaping/comments and/or preserve blank lines